# Joining 3 MySQL tables to display all data

Tags: mysql, database

I've read countless threads on stackoverflow regarding matters similar to this, but I'm struggling to solve my issue and to understand the various MySQL JOIN queries. I'm in the early days of learning MySQL, and any help would be appreciated.

I have 3 tables:

1. auction
2. category
3. lot

auction and category simply have a unique primary key and an auction date, category title column respectively.

lot displays the lot title, lot description etc... and links to the auction and category table using the their respective ID's.

**I simply wish to display the lot table showing all rows including the auction date and category title.**

My failed attempt:

```
SELECT l.lotid, l.lotnumber, l.lottitle, l.lotdescription, c.categorytitle, a.auctiondate, l.estimatefrom, l.estimateto, l.photo, l.datecreated, l.lastmodified 
FROM lot l
JOIN category c ON l.categoryid = c.categoryid
JOIN auction a ON l.auctionid = a.auctionid
ORDER BY l.lotnumber;
```

This is simply acting like a WHERE query, as I'm sure it should, omitting any rows whereby `categorytitle` and `auctiondate` do not match

Is there a simple fix?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    l.lotid, 
    l.lotnumber, 
    l.lottitle, 
    l.lotdescription, 
    IFNULL(c.categorytitle,'n/a'), 
    IFNULL(a.auctiondate,'n/a'), 
    l.estimatefrom, 
    l.estimateto, 
    l.photo, 
    l.datecreated, 
    l.lastmodified 
FROM 
    lot l
LEFT JOIN category c 
    ON l.categoryid = c.categoryid
LEFT JOIN auction a 
    ON l.auctionid = a.auctionid
ORDER BY 
    l.lotnumber;
```

Comment: That's improved things, however now the rows where categorytitle and auctiondate don't match have lost their auctiondate - it is replaced with NULL ??

Comment: @SamHolguin its replaced with 'n/a' ... `IFNULL(c.categorytitle,'n/a')`

Comment: apologies, I missed your SELECT IFNULL inclusion. This again has improved things :) however, I wish to show all auction dates for each lot. Sorry I wasn't clear on this. Each lot has an auction ID which links to the auction table to identify it's date, and I wish to show all of these

Comment: looking at the diagram below, would FULL OUTTER JOIN work? you could then remove any NULL rows

Comment: it depends on what you want... if you need all the rows from all the tables then `FULL OUTER JOIN` is the way to go

Comment: In this instance I wish to display the full list of lots, with each lot having an auctiondate and categorytitle in place of auctionid and category id. I'll try figure it out, cheers for your help

Comment: COALESCE() conforms to the SQL standard. Also, it's more scalable and it looks nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the left join or right to reduce the number of rows and will get the appropriate data.

Here is tutorials: [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) & [RIGHT JOIN](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32).

Comment: Thank you for these. I wish to display all rows though in this instance, and I don't want to show a NULL value where a data value was

Comment: @SamHolguin then you need use is null in where clause

Comment: Looking at FULL JOIN, I still won't get what I am after...that just displays matches and all no matches and still uses NULL :) I am completely lost!! haha

Comment: I thought this would be so simple...just expand from one JOIN to two and it should work

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of my time and patience, I simply coded this the long way, throwing in a subquery to get the result I wanted:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT l.lotid, l.lotnumber, l.lottitle, l.lotdescription, c.categorytitle, l.estimatefrom, l.estimateto, l.photo, l.datecreated, l.lastmodified 
         FROM lot l
         JOIN category c ON l.categoryid = c.categoryid
         ORDER BY l.lotnumber";

if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo '<p class="warning">Error executing SELECT query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error . "</p>";
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

?>
    <div class="clearfix lot-bg">       
        <p>Lot Number: <span><?php echo $row[1]; ?></span></p>
        <p>Lot Title: <span><?php echo $row[2]; ?></span></p>
        <p>Lot Description: <span><?php echo $row[3]; ?></span></p>
        <p>Category: <span><?php echo $row[4]; ?></span></p>

        <?php

        $subquery = "SELECT a. auctiondate 
                     FROM lot l
                     JOIN auction a ON l.auctionid = a.auctionid
                     WHERE lotid = $row[0]";

        if ($subresult = $mysqli->query($subquery)) {

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($subquery)) {

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            $subrows = $stmt->num_rows;

               for ($j = 0; $j < $subrows; ++$j) {
                    while ($subrow = $subresult->fetch_row()) {
                        echo '<p>Auction Date: <span>' . $subrow[0] . '</span></p>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
        $subresult->close();

        ?>

        <p>Estimate:  <span>£<?php echo $row[5]; ?> - £<?php echo $row[6]; ?></span></p>
        <p>Date Created: <span><?php echo $row[8]; ?></span></p>
        <p>Last-Modified:  <span><?php echo $row[9]; ?></span></p>
        <figure><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href='img/<?php echo $row[7]; ?>'><img src='img/<?php echo $row[7]; ?>'></a></figure>

        <div class="buttons">           
            <form class="form-signin form-delete" action="lot.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
                <input type="hidden" name="lotid" value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>' />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block">DELETE</button>
            </form>
            <form class="form-signin form-delete" action="lotupdate.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes" />
                <input type="hidden" name="lotid" value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>' />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block">EDIT</button>
            </form>
            <form class="form-signin form-delete" action="lotupdate.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="photo" value="yes" />
                <input type="hidden" name="lotid" value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>' />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block">PHOTO</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php

    }
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```